# Kalman Filter - Dynamic System

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the two equations below

$$ \begin{aligned} 300x + 400y &= 700 \\ 100x + 133y &= 233 \end{aligned}$$

how can one find a solution for those equations using Kalman filter (and suppose the same with increasing the constant by $1$?

Comment: Are you sure that's the task you're given?

Comment: I find the question inscrutable.  Kalman filtering seems to me like a ridiculous way to solve the task that was listed, so I wonder what your real problem is.  It is like asking what is the best way to make toast for my breakfast using a 747 jet; the best way is to ignore the 747 and use a toaster.  What's the motivation for your question?  What's the context where you encountered this specific task?

Comment: Where is the dynamical system?